# Почему store не обновляет компоненты когда изменилось его состояние (mobx)?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Когда вызывается setActiveCandidate меняются данные в this.state. Однако компоненты которые подписаны на этот store не обновляются.

```
import { decorate, observable, configure, action, computed ,autorun } from "mobx";


configure({ enforceActions: true }); // Не допускать изменение состояния вне actions

class Store {

  // Состояние с которым можно работать
  state = {
    supportCompare:
      "Уровень",
    activeCandidate: null,
    candidats: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Владимир Путин (2018)",
        percent: "70"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Сергей Собянин (2013)",
        percent: "54"
      }
    ]
  };

  setActiveCandidate(activeId) {
    if (activeId !== this.activeCandidate) {
      this.state = { ...this.state, activeCandidate: activeId };
    }

    this.state.supportCompare = '111';
  }

  get activeCandidate() {
    return this.state.activeCandidat;
  }
  get candidats() {
    return this.state.candidats;
  }
  get supportCompare() {
    return this.state.supportCompare;
  }
}

decorate(Store, {
  // Наблюдаемое свойство
  state: observable,
  updateCount: observable,

  // Действие и изменение объекта
  setActiveCandidate: action, // выставляем активныного кандидата

  supportCompare: computed,
  candidats: computed, // получаем список кандидатов
  activeCandidate: computed // активный выбранный кандидат
});



export default Store;
```

---

Файл где App

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import Store from "./store/store";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

import Elections2018 from "./components/Elections/Elections2018";

const appStore = new Store();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Elections2018 store={appStore} />;
  }
}

App = observer(App)

export default App;
```

Comment: return this.state.activeCandida( t ); а не Candida( te), может поэтому не отрисовывается?

Comment: Да, спасибо!  Я так понял, что если в компоненте не используются переменные из store то он не будет перерисовываться.

Comment: Да. Именно та переменная или геттер, для которых сделан computed.